# 'And', 'Or' operators in Minizinc?

Tags: boolean, operators, minizinc

This is probably an easy answer, like *no* there are is no 'or' or 'and' operators in Minizinc, but I can't seem to find anything related to it on google.

In most programming languages you can do this:

`boolean s = (a != 1 && b != 2);`

But nowhere can I find a Minizinc version of this statement, like:
`constraint a != 1 and b != 2;`

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disjunction (or) and conjunction (and) are written in MiniZinc as `\/` and `/\` respectively.

So your example should be written as

```
constraint a != 1 /\ b != 2;
```

See a little more here: https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/modelling2.html?highlight=conjunction